# Qt signal argument thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

Suppose I have a signal `sendImage(const QImage&)` that is connected to a slot `updateLabel(const QImage&)` in an other thread, which will convert the QImage to a QPixmap then place it in a QLabel. Now I'm wondering, if I use a function `const QImage& prepareImage()` as the argument of the signal e.g. `emit sendImage(prepareImage())`, and the signal is emitted dozens of times per seconds, is it thread safe or is there a possibility that a race condition occurs between prepareImage and updateLabel both accessing the image at the same time thus crashing the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thankfully, Qt protects you from yourself and will copy the image so that you don't shoot yourself in the foot. The copying will be done upon signal's emission, and is done from inside of the implementation of the signal - here, the copying is done when `Object::source` is on the call stack.

Given that a `QImage` is implicitly shared, the initial copy will be cheap, but if the main thread then modifies the source image, it will force a deep copy. If your modifications are such that the source is discarded, it'll be more efficient to replace the source image with the new one instead of "modifying" it.

Output:

```
data is at 0x7fff5fbffbf8 in main thread QThread(0x10250a700)
0x7fff5fbffbf8 was copied to 0x1025115d0 in thread QThread(0x10250a700)
got 0x1025115d0 in thread QThread(0x7fff5fbffb80)
```

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

class Copyable {
public:
   Copyable() {}
   Copyable(const Copyable & src) {
      qDebug() << static_cast<const void*>(&src) << "was copied to"
               << static_cast<void*>(this) << "in thread" << QThread::currentThread();
   }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Copyable)

class Object : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Q_SIGNAL void source(const Copyable &);
   Q_SLOT void sink(const Copyable & data) {
      qDebug() << "got" << static_cast<const void*>(&data) << "in thread"
               << QThread::currentThread();
      // Queue a quit since we are racing with app.exec(). qApp->quit() is a no-op before
      // the app.exec() has had a chance to block.
      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qApp, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);
   }
};

class Thread : public QThread { public: ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); } };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
   Copyable data;
   qDebug() << "data is at" << static_cast<void*>(&data) << "in main thread" << app.thread();
   qRegisterMetaType<Copyable>();
   Object o1, o2;
   Thread thread;
   o2.moveToThread(&thread);
   thread.start();
   o2.connect(&o1, &Object::source, &o2, &Object::sink);
   emit o1.source(data);
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So even though the QImage itself is copied, the data pointed by QImage still stays the same in both threads as long as I don't modify the data in processImage()? If instead of `const QImage&` I used simply QImage then it would perfom a deep copy? As I need to modify the source image, is there then any difference whether I use a const reference or not as far as performance goes?

Comment: Also, apparently if after emitting the signal, both threads start to modify the data shared by both copies of QImage, this will cause a race condition, right?

Comment: @user2563661 `QImage` will only perform a deep copy when it is needed, or when you explicitly call `detach`. You can't ever cause a deep copy by copying the `QImage` instance.

Comment: @user2563661 The whole point of implicit sharing is that it's supposed to be safe. When both threads start to modify the data, one thread will win, block the other thread, and perform a copy. Every `QImage` operation can potentially synchronize and copy the image.

Comment: So is there any difference between using a const reference or passing by value on a signal?

Comment: @user2563661 Yes. Using the const reference will save you from the cost of one (shallow) copy. Since a shallow copy (at least) forces a cacheline sync across all cores as a means of synchronization, it should still be avoided. In the case of signals, not using a const reference is premature pessimization. You're wasting performance for no reason whatsoever. If you are passing classes that are not implicitly shared, such as `std::` containers, you'll be forcing a deep copy and that's being very wasteful for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the connection between SIGNAL and SLOT.

If you are using the default one, which is `Qt::AutoConnection`, it acts like  `Qt::QueuedConnection` for cross-thread connections.

In Queued Connection, all signal parameters are copied to the queue and passed by value even though you pass them by reference.

Hence, there is no possibility that a race condition occurs.

Note : QImage implements CopyOnWrite (Implicit Sharing) which means if you manage to change the internal buffer of QImage somehow, your synchronization will blow up.

Comment: Qt's implicit sharing is thread-safe as long as you operate on separate instances of `QImage`. Since the queued slot call receives a copy of the image - a separate instance - everything is safe. This is a case of Qt preventing one from doing very stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't quite understand what do you mean by:

> is there a possibility that a race condition occurs between prepareImage and updateLabel both accessing the image at the same time

One thread has created an object and (let us assume for a moment this is the same object) the other one is using it. Where exactly is the moment when both threads are using it at the same time?

Even if it happens, in your case QImage created in first thread will be copied and passed to another one, so this is not the same object.

Comment: Ok, I evidently wasn't clear enough. The image is a member variable of my thread class and is only created once when the program starts. On the other hand the data in the QImage is constantly processed in prepareImage(). As you can see the signal emits a const reference of the image, so in effect both threads should be accessing the same image.

Comment: @user2563661 Thankfully, Qt will protect you from yourself and copy the image so that you don't shoot yourself in the foot.